# Why does calling a member function as if it were static (when it's not) work in C++?

Tags: c++, static-methods

According to my understanding of C++, the following code is erroneous.

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {
private:
  int num_;

public:
  Test(int n) : num_(n) {}
  void printNum() { std::cout << num_ << '\n'; }
  void weird() { Test::printNum(); }
};

int main() {
  Test t(10);
  t.weird();
  return 0;
}
```

`Test::weird()` calls `Test::printNum()` as it would a static member function. However, `Test::printNum()` accesses an instance attribute and is clearly not static. Yet, the code compiles and runs to output `10`.

My compiler is Apple LLVM version 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)

What am I missing?

Comment: In this context the class name qualifier acts as a disambiguator and is perfectly legal and in some cases (eg. inheritance) it is required to differentiate which of several similar named functions gets invoked.

Comment: @Galik: Please do not answer questions in the comments section, which is for requesting clarification.

Comment: _"is clearly not a class method"_ Maybe it's just that your terminology is off, but it's definitely a "method" aka member function.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes, I clarified in the first instance that by "class method", I mean "static method". I will edit the question for improved clarity.

Comment: You'd better avoid "method" entirely. It's not a C++ term and has too many possible meanings borrowed and/or corrupted from other domains. Use standard terminology where possible.

Comment: Good question! This will effectively increase your C++ knowledge. Good job!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use printNum(); instead of this->printNum(); .

When you inherit classes, you use NameOfClass::printNum(); to use the printNum(); you want.

Example:

```
class A { public: void test() { std::cout << "hey" << std:endl; } }
class B : public A { public: void test() { std::cout << "oh" << std:endl; } }
class C : public B { public: void test() { A::test(); } }
```

So Test::printNum(); is just the call to the method printNum(); of this class.

Comment: All true, but rather misleading. The ability to qualify the name of the function has little to do with inheritance beyond the fact that it's convenient for invoking base members and, even if it did, this would not explain why the OP thinks it's reserved for calls to `static` member functions or explain why instead it's not.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: It's an answer, wsaleem didn't understand why it was working, this answer is enough to give him an idea of why it works. Lightness Races in Orbit wrote a detailed one, I upvoted it.

Answer (score 19):

> What am I missing?

You're wrong about this:

> `Test::weird()` calls `Test::printNum()` as a class (static) method.

It's not being called as a `static` method. It can't be, because it's not one.

Within a member function, you do not need an object reference or pointer (e.g. `this`) to call another member function. So you can write either of these:

```
this->printNum();
printNum();
```

The full name of `printNum` is actually `Test::printNum`, so you can do these too:

```
this->Test::printNum();
Test::printNum();
```

Outside of a member function, the second option in both cases is wrong because the function is not static and you did not provide an object reference or pointer.

Outside of a member function you'd also *have* to write the `Test::` otherwise the compiler wouldn't know which `printNum` you're talking about, but that in itself doesn't force the call to be a "static" call. It'll be a static call iff the member function is static; period!

Comment: _"Outside of a member function you'd also have to write the Test:: otherwise the compiler wouldn't know which printNum you're talking about"_. I suppose the compiler would also not know which instance to call the function for.

Comment: @wsaleem: While true, that has nothing to do with whether you wrote `Test::` or not (see the _previous_ paragraph! _"the function is not static and you did not provide an object reference or pointer"_), which is rather the point here.

Comment: Your answer is great, I was conflicted, and I [researched what to do](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255150/how-to-choose-between-multiple-correct-answers). Your answer told me things I mostly knew. The one I accepted includes your answer _and_ shows a use case demonstrating why the unintuitive (to me) syntax is necessary. That said, I acknowledge your effort in improving the post and my understanding. Thank you. And I was expecting your comment above! But, as the meta link says, I had to choose the answer that helped me more. So I went with the other answer.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Upvoted because it's OK and the other answer here (currently selected as solutoin) is not. However, the last paragraph is not easy to understand, and can easily mislead. I suggest you delete or rewrite it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit *Within a member function, you do not need an object reference or pointer (e.g. this) to call another member function.* Except (the annoying and initially strange looking case) when you use an inherited member function from a dependent base class, for which you need to use `this->...` or qualified name lookup. +1 for the answer.

Comment: @vsoftco: Mmm yeah that's probably worth a footnote actually

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: What about it is difficult to understand? What misleadings do you envision it causing?

Comment: @wsaleem: The one you accepted actually _doesn't_ include my answer, instead choosing to describe unrelated scenarios. That's the only reason I asked. But it's up to you. \*shrug\*

Comment: I am, however, curious as to which comedian decided to downvote this.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: que?